# Send parameters to ActionResult method and return a file - asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, file

I'm trying to make a page that when a button is clicked a file starts downloading.  The problem I'm having is I would like to send parameters to my ActionResult method that returns the File, but when I try sending JSON with post or get the ActionResult method gets called but the file does not get sent to the browser to be downloaded.  If I type in the link to that controller method the file downloads fine. I can't just have a link to the file because I need to dynamically change the file depending on what options are selected on the webpage.

I get the feeling I may be attacking this the wrong way, any incite would be helpful.

I'm using Asp.net MVC 3 and Jquery, thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I guess there is a way to send params to an action result without JSON, just with JavaScript, I think this would help me solve my problem too, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: do you have to use JSON.  I did a similar thing a couple of days ago and I have the code but without using JSON?

Comment: I prefer to use JSON for this project but I'd like to see what you did regardless.

Comment: is there an email address or something I can send it to?

Comment: The email in my profile works, thanks.

Comment: I don't see an email address there.

Comment: Sorry, daniel.somers@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

you can return the `file path` in the `json` response and then redirect to that path like

```
$.post("",{data:yourData,function(data){

 if(data.filepath!='')
 location.href=data.filepath;//this will force the browser download dialogue 
}});
```

in the controller

```
public ActionResult GetFile(/*params*/){ 
 //your code
 var filepath="some path";
 return Json(new { filepath=filepath});
}
```

Comment: I don't think that helps me because I'm not trying to return a static file, I'm trying to generate the file based on the params sent to the controller.  Unless I can somehow generate a new file path for each file I generate. I don't really want to do something like that.